# how to enable host compilation but not cross compilation on yocto on certain files

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, openwrt

I am trying to build gutenprint 5.2.14 for arm platform using yocto project "devtool". During the compile process, I am getting this error for the file "lt-extract-strings" saying cannot binary execute file: Exec format error

Upon looking at the file, it a 32-bit arm-executable.

OpenWRT says to implement this when doing cross-compilation.

```
define Build/Compile
    # Replace the cross-compiled "extract-string" by a shell-script that
    # runs the host's own compiled version (gutenprint needs to run this)
    (cd $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) && $(MAKE) -C src/xml extract-strings && \
    $(RM) src/xml/extract-strings && \
    echo '#!/bin/sh' > src/xml/extract-strings && \
    echo 'exec $(HOST_BUILD_DIR)/src/xml/extract-strings  "$$$$@" ' \
    >> src/xml/extract-strings && chmod +x src/xml/extract-strings && cp src/xml/extract-strings /tmp/)
    $(call Build/Compile/Default)
endef
```

the link to the file is [here](https://github.com/FranciscoBorges/openwrt-printing-packages/blob/master/net/gutenprint/Makefile)

I tried looking for sources on how to implement this fix above in a yocto recipe but I had no luck finding it. Can someone help me solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you check old [gutenprint](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/recipes/gutenprint/gutenprint_5.1.3.bb) recipe, you can see that it disables every native steps through --disable-x in standard recipe, and enable it in [native recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/recipes/gutenprint/gutenprint-native_5.1.3.bb), then copy files from one to another. Another solution is to patch Makefile and use `_class-target` and `_class-native` suffixes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a newbie in yocto. I have generated the recipe for this package using devtool command. Can you walk me through or provide me with any documentation on how to make a native recipe ?

Comment: Just suffix recipe file with `-native` and add `inherit native` inside.

Comment: BTW, there is pretty much everything in [Yocto mega manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html)

Comment: should create a new recipe for that using devtool?

Comment: You can just duplicate your recipe file and make the adjustments, or maybe try `--also-native` devtool option, never tried it